# How to fix Eclipse (JEE Juno SR1) black background tool-tips in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, eclipse

This seems to be a fairly common issue but I could not find any help regarding Ubuntu 12.10 version.

I'm a rookie at Ubuntu but I think that the solutions for the older versions could not be used at Quantal Quetzal.

Am I missing something?

[image: Black tooltips at Eclipse]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it using GNOME Color Chooser!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse, go to Window > Preferences. A new window will open.
There open the General detail discloser, then open Appearance, click on Colors and Fonts and voila! Change it to your liking.

I'm on a Mac right now, but the window is the same (and please consider this is Android Developer Tools, a eclipse based IDE):
!http://s17.postimage.org/w721i79jz/Screen_Shot_2013_02_05_at_10_11_52_PM.png

Comment: (of course, under OSX, its under Eclipse > Preferences, right next to the Apple logo, to get to the same window)

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it did not work but I've solved the problema with GNOME Color Chooser program. :)

Comment: Weird! But to know you got it working. Also good to know you decided to give Ubuntu a shot, old buddy!

Comment: I'm giving Linux and Java a shot! :)